# How do I know contents of domain.xml using glassfish package

Tags: glassfish

I creating some application, using glassfish v4 web container.
I want to know "how to get properties of domain.xml({GLASSFISH_HOME}/glassfish/domains/{APPLICATION_NAME}/config/domain.xml) in java source using glassfish package"
Actually I need a glassfish application root context path